# Starling scaffold project showing blank texture

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am building an app using Starling and have imported the scaffold project however whenever I call getTextureAtlas() it doesn't show the image

```
this.mLogo = new Image(Assets.getAtlasTexture("powered_by_starling"));
this.mLogo.x = 0;
this.mLogo.y = 0;
this.addChild(this.mLogo);
```

There are no errors so I am guessing it can find the texture. If I change the name to something that doesn't exist it throws an error 'texture cannot be null'. I am also using

```
Assets.contentScaleFactor = Starling.current.contentScaleFactor;
```

and everything is pretty much a standard import of the scaffold as is however I am using Feathers UI screen navigator but I haven't had a blank image issue on other projects.

Edit: I can't seem to get the sprite to work within a class that extends feathers.controls.Screen

Answer (score 0):

Is getAtlasTexture a function that you wrote? Are you using starlings asset manager? If that's the case, you will need a instance of that class, not static method call.

Anyway, try using the Texture class and the static method it offers. You don't need atlas(sprite sheet) for a Image - you will need it however for MovieClip.

```
Texture.fromBitmap
Texture.fromBitmapData
```

.... and others, check documentation

If your graphics are embedded, then use this:

```
var _img:Image = new Image(Texture.fromBitmap(new Assets.EmbeddedGraphic()));
```

Comment: No getAtlasTexture is part of the Starling scaffold example project but using the function works when a class extends Starling Sprite instead of the Feathers Screen Navigator.

Comment: @Kere Puki ah, so you are extending the Screen Navigator, ok, sorry. Didn't work with that, but quick look on the class itself tells that you need to use this.addScreen( "theImage", new Image(Assets.getAtlasTexture("powered_by_starling"))); to add screens to display, and then this.showScreen("theImage"); to show it. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Are you using atf? because the same happened to me until I used png and then it worked